# No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"

Tags: python, wsdl, suds

I'm new to Python and trying to work with WSDL to generate data.

```
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> client = Client('http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/datafeed.cfc?WSDL')
>>> result = client.service.SalesDetailJSON(EventGUID='5789ADDC-6A64-E411-B196-0025B3A62EEE')
No handlers could be found for logger "suds.client"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/suds/client.py", line 535, in __call__
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/suds/client.py", line 595, in invoke
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/suds/client.py", line 630, in send
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/suds/client.py", line 681, in failed
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/suds/bindings/binding.py", line 230, in get_fault
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getChild'
```

I used one of the method from print client:

```
Service ( DataFeedService ) tns="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
       Prefixes (2)
          ns0 = "http://rpc.xml.coldfusion"
          ns1 = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
       Ports (1):
          (datafeed.cfc)
             Methods (2):
                SalesDetail(xs:double Page, xs:double RecPP, xs:string EventGUID, xs:string LastUpdated, xs:boolean IncludeSurvey, xs:string SurveyKey, )
                SalesDetailJSON(xs:string EventGUID, xs:string LastUpdated, xs:string NoFinancials, )
             Types (49):
                ...........
```

My goal is to convert and store XML every hour. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup a looger first to get ride of this message. Take a look at https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#LOGGING and 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html (or https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html depending on your version of python). However something like this should solve the problem:

```
>>> import logging
>>> from suds.client import Client
>>> logger = logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
>>> # ...
```